# splitting a big json file and setting the name of the output file

Tags: python, json, perl, shell, awk

I have a large file of JSON objects (more than 12000 lines) that looks like:

```
{
     "System": "2334", 
     "Id": "AP64531346-2016055553824", 
     "dtis": "106165099", 
     "Type": "Up",
     ... (in total, 112 lines per record)
}
{
     "System": "873", 
     "Id": "AP24531346-20160676553824", 
     "dtis": "1261699", 
     "Type": "Up",
     ... (in total, 112 lines per record)
}
```

I want to split the big file in small files each one with one entrance (112 lines) and set the name of each piece as the value of the "Id", i mean for example AP64531346-2016055553824.txt and AP24531346-20160676553824 respectively.

I tried with the GNU Split but i can't set the name of each file as the Id plus .txt.

```
split -l 112 ../bigfile.csv
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two steps: first you generate the generically named files with

```
split -l 112 ../bigfile.csv
```

Now you have files named `xaa`, `xab` etc. I assume these are the only files in the directory. Now you can loop over them, extract the Id and rename them:

```
for file in *; do
    newname="$(grep -m 1 -Po '(?<="Id": ")[^"]+' "$file")"
    mv "$file" "$newname.txt"
done
```

`grep -o` extracts only the match, and uses a zero-width "look-behind" to get the Id line. Look-arounds are only available when using the Perl regex engine (`-P`). `-m 1` stops after the first match so you don't go through the whole file when you know the first match is good enough.

<sub>This of course breaks badly when there aren't 112 lines per block – a [proper solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34844677/3266847) would parse the file.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to place each of the JSON documents in its own file. You can use JSON::XS's incremental parser to do that.

```
use JSON::XS qw( );

my $json = JSON::XS->utf8->new();

local $/ = \(1024*1024)
while (<>) {
   for my $obj ($json->incr_parse($_)) {
      my $id = $obj->{Id};
      open(my $fh, '>', $id . ".txt")
         or die $!;
      print($fh $json->encode($obj));
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will cause the keys in the data to come out in a different order than the original.  If the data is actually as described, it might be better to `$/ = "\n}\n"; while (my $record = <>) { my $id = $json->decode($record)->{Id}; open(my $fh,...) or die; print $fh $record }` (only with error checking)

Comment: @ysth, Correct, but key order is meaningless in JSON. As for the rest of the comment, why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: seemed too little different from yours

Comment: @ysth, Completely different approach as far as I'm concerned, but whatever

Comment: @ysth: I prefer your solution and agree that you should post it

Answer (score 1):

A general approach to the task (i.e., an approach that makes no assumptions about the stream of JSON entities in the input file, other than that they are valid JSON entities) is illustrated by the following "one-liner":

```
jq -cr '"\(.Id)\t\(.)"' | awk -F\\t '{print $2 > "/tmp/"$1".json"}'
```

This uses the "JSON query" ([jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)) command-line processor, which is available on many platforms.

If you want each of the new files to be pretty-printed then you can use jq for that as well in a second step, e.g.:

```
ls *.json | while read f ; do jq . "$f" > "$f.tmp" && mv "$f.tmp" "$f" ; done
```

Comment: You are aware that what OP posted is not valid JSON, but rater multiply snippets of valid JSON combined in one file?

Comment: You are aware that I edited the post accordingly, 11 hours or so before your comment?

Answer (score 1):

JSON structure is highly compatible with perl data structure so quick way to separate record in distinct file can be use of eval. Considering you json is not holding ":" in values

```
local $/ = undef;
open FILE, "Testjson.txt" or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
my $string = <BiGFILE>;
close FILE;
$string =~ s/:/,/g;  
$jsonStr = eval $string;

foreach my $record (@{$jsonStr}) {
 print $record->{'Id'} . "\n";
}
```